# Python pandas: Assign label based on sorted values per row, excluding NaNs

Tags: python, pandas, sorting, numpy

I want to assign the position of every value based on its position within the sorted value-list per row (excluding NaNs). I just can't figure out how to do this in an elegant way with pandas.

I think it's easier to explain in an example:

```
                A         B        C           D
Date                                              
2002-02-28 -0.051272 -0.005851 -0.012669       NaN
2002-03-29  0.103416  0.050121  0.050203       0.5
2002-04-30 -0.090579 -0.042308  0.019293       0.03
2002-05-31  0.160239 -0.078983  0.047319       0.66
```

For every row, I want to do the following:

- Exclude NaNs
- Calculate the position of the value within the list of sorted values in that row and assign this number (position 1 being the smallest (negative) number and position N being the biggest positive number)

The result would be:

```
                A         B        C         D
Date                                              
2002-02-28      1         3       2         NaN
2002-03-29      3         1       2          4
2002-04-30      1         2       3          4
2002-05-31      3         1       2          4
```

In a second step, I than want to make a 3-row "rolling" function per column which checks whether the current row and the 2 rows before within one colum were smaller then a certain threshold X and in case it is, then display the average of those 3 values, else just note down NaN. In case any of those 3 values is NaN, than just note down NaN. Can only be calculated from 2002-04-30 ongoing, because needs at least 3 values. For column D, this would yield "NaN" in row 2002-04-30 because there are only two numeric values beforehand. For Column D and row 2002-05-31 it would also yield "NaN" because the 3 values are 4, 4 and 4 with 4 being greater then the treshold.

Let's say the threshold X=3. (I leave out column D because my explanations make the data to wide):

E.g.:

```
                A           B                C         
Date                                              
2002-02-28      NaN        NaN              NaN        
2002-03-29      NaN        NaN              NaN        
2002-04-30   Avg(1,3,1)    Avg(3,1,2)    Avg(2+2+3)         
2002-05-31   Avg(3,1,3)    Avg(1,2,1)    Avg(2+3+2)
```

**EDIT**:
I think I got both steps myself. Could you please evaluate whether this is correct and sensible?:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame(data={'X': [0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.4], 'Y': [0.5, -0.2, np.NaN, -1], 'Z': [np.NaN, -0.21, -5, 10]})
df.apply(lambda row: [sorted([y for y in row if not np.isnan(y)]).index(x)+1 if not np.isnan(x) else np.NaN for x in row], axis=1)

df:
     X    Y      Z
0  0.1  0.5    NaN
1  0.2 -0.2  -0.21
2  0.3  NaN  -5.00
3  0.4 -1.0  10.00

After .apply:
     X    Y    Z
0  1.0  2.0  NaN
1  3.0  2.0  1.0
2  2.0  NaN  1.0
3  2.0  1.0  3.0


# Step 2 with new examplatory data and only one column
df = pd.DataFrame(data={'A': [1,2,3,np.NaN,3,1,3,4,3,np.NaN,2,2,1,2]})
threshold = 3
df['A_rolling'] = df['A'].rolling(window=3, min_periods=3).apply(lambda x: x.mean() if all([val <= threshold for val in x]) else np.NaN)

      A  A_rolling
0   1.0        NaN
1   2.0        NaN
2   3.0   2.000000
3   NaN        NaN
4   3.0        NaN
5   1.0        NaN
6   3.0   2.333333
7   4.0        NaN
8   3.0        NaN
9   NaN        NaN
10  2.0        NaN
11  2.0        NaN
12  1.0   1.666667
13  2.0   1.666667
```

So only gotta run it for all columns now :)

Any ideas?
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For step one you could use the `rank` method:

```
step1 = df.rank(axis=1)
```

```
             A    B    C    D
Date                          
2002-02-28  1.0  3.0  2.0  NaN
2002-03-29  3.0  1.0  2.0  4.0
2002-04-30  1.0  2.0  3.0  4.0
2002-05-31  3.0  1.0  2.0  4.0
```

For step two it might be less verbose to replace all values greater than threshold with `NaN`s and run a rolling mean:

```
threshold = 3
step1[step1 > threshold] = pd.np.NaN
step2 = step1.rolling(window=3, min_periods=3).mean()
```

```
                  A         B         C   D
Date                                        
2002-02-28       NaN       NaN       NaN NaN
2002-03-29       NaN       NaN       NaN NaN
2002-04-30  1.666667  2.000000  2.333333 NaN
2002-05-31  2.333333  1.333333  2.333333 NaN
```

Comment: Really nice solution. Would be nice if you drop the last 'D' column in step2.

Comment: @Bharath shetty: No need to as this was only examplatory; I wanted to avoid lineabreaks in the displaying in the dataframe above :) I will have a look at your examples later on, but it looks really really good as of now, very clear and much more elegant than mine :)